# Reducing simultaneously a pair of fractions $\frac{a^2}{b},\frac{ a^3}{c}$ using only gcds

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic

Given three positive integers $a,b,c$ and I want to find the smallest positive integers $a', b', c'$ such that 
$$ \frac{a^2}{b} = \frac{a'^2}{b'}  \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{a^3}{c} = \frac{a'^3}{c'} $$
in other words I want to find the largest integer $d$ such that 
$$ d\vert a, \quad d^2 \vert b \quad \text{and} \quad  d^3 \vert c $$

I wonder wether I can find $d$ using a fast algorithm reliying only divisibility, root extraction or computing gcds (greatest common divisor), without relying in factorization or iteration over the possible divisors.

More generally I would like to know a polynomial time algorithm to reduce in the same way the quotients

$$ \frac{a^2}{b}, \frac{a^3}{c}, \frac{a^4}{d}, \dots , \frac{a^t}{m}$$

where $a,b,c,\dots,m$ and $t$ are positive integers.

Comment: It seems unlikely this can be done as an algorithm working for any choices of $a,b,c,$ since for example given $n>0$ one can choose $(a,b,c)=(n,n,n^3)$ and then the algorithm would extract the largest square which divides $n.$ I don't see how to do that via gcd only. On the other hand since in another comment you allow root extraction, maybe this is OK if also you allow taking floor of a number.

Comment: You are right, there is no known algorithm even to know if an integer is square-free which does not rely in factorization. Thanks, I hadn't think in your example.

Comment: Esteban: With the idea that one can get the largest square factor of an integer $n$ with such an algorithm as you are looking for, consider two large primes $p,q$ and the case of $n=p^2q$. Unless you know this factorization already, the algorithm would somehow find the largest square, here the $p^2$. Thus one would have a "fast" algorithm to factor numbers of type $p^2q$ which I think is not known.

Answer (score 0):

How about looking for the gcd $g$ of $a^6$, $b^3$ and $c^2$ and then taking the "truncated 6-th root" (or whatever you would call it) of that, i.e. take $d$ to be the largest integer such that $d^6\,|\,g\;$?

Comment: You would need either to factor $g$ in order to find $d$ or to iterate over the integers up to $\sqrt[6]g$. However I'm changing the question to allow root extraction and avoid iteration. What I'm looking for is a fast way to compute it.